# NestJS - How to call service method from mongoose schema inside custom validation

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I have two modules-

courses

```
-courses.module.ts
-courses.services.ts
-courses.schema.ts
-courses.controller.ts
```

groups

```
-groups.module.ts
-groups.services.ts
-groups.schema.ts
-groups.controller.ts
```

Content of courses.module.ts is-

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';
import { CoursesController } from './courses.controller';
import { MongooseModule, getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { CourseSchema } from './schemas/course.schema';
import { GroupsService } from 'src/groups/groups.service';
import { GroupsModule } from 'src/groups/groups.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ 
      name: 'Course', schema: CourseSchema }]),
    GroupsModule,

  ],

  providers: [
    CoursesService,
  ],
  controllers: [CoursesController],
  exports: [CoursesService],
})
export class CoursesModule {}
```

Content of groups.module.ts is-

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GroupsService } from './groups.service';
import { GroupsController } from './groups.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { GroupSchema } from './schemas/group.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Group', schema: GroupSchema }]),
  ],
  providers: [GroupsService],
  controllers: [GroupsController],
  exports:[
    GroupsService, 
  ]
})
export class GroupsModule {}
```

I want to call methods of GroupsService inside courses.schema.ts like this-

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { GroupsService } from 'src/groups/groups.service';
import { GroupsModule } from 'src/groups/groups.module';
import { GroupSchema } from 'src/groups/schemas/group.schema';


export const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    groupId: {
        type: Number,
        isAsync: true,
        validate(value) {
            if(GroupsService.getByCode()==='xyz'){
              return false;
            }

        }
    },
})
```

How can I achieve this? I have gone through the documentation of NestJS but didn't find any appropriate method to inject service directly inside schema and access the service methods during custom validation.

Answer (score 2):

In your main.ts exports the app reference.

```
export let app;
async function bootstrap() {
   app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
}
bootstrap();
```

Then in your schema file you may do something like this

```
import { app } from 'path/to/main.ts';

const service = app.get(GroupsService);
```

Here you are using the service container to get a reference from the GroupsService.

Comment: Bit late, but something I've found with this approach is that unit testing becomes more difficult since the schema gets the service through the AppModule and not from say a TestModule created in a unit test. Still a working solution tho